# A question about precision

Tags: precision-recall, confusion-matrix, precision, churn

We have 2 Classification models (Random forest on balanced Data Set), the first one classify a Bank's client as a Churner (closing his account) or an active client, the second one classify a Bank's client as a dormant (inactive) account holder or an active client.

We have tested the model on a data set, and we have two confusion matrices.

What's the Precision of every model? and is there a way estimate the precision of the two models?

Comment: Just curious; "the first one classify a Bank's client as a Churner (closing his account) --> (Random forest on balanced Data Set)"! How is it Balanced?! Are you saying after under/over sampling?

Comment: yes after under/over sampling

Comment: I know the question is simple, but it has caused a divergence of opinions in my work place, maybe some answers will help

Comment: I think you have to edit/rephrase your question. What you have asked, "we have two confusion matrices....what's the Precision of every model?" sounds pretty straightforward:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/precision-recall-and-f-measure-for-imbalanced-classification/

Comment: Well it is not straightforward for the guys i work with, they somehow think that becuase there's 3 different outputs of the two models, the precision shoul be equal to (TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN), which is actually the accuracy of the model